# Identifier 'ChatFeed' has already been declared

Tags: reactjs

```
import { ChatEngine, ChatFeed } from 'react-chat-engine';
import ChatFeed from './components/chatFeed';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
    return(

        <ChatEngine
            height="100vh"
            projectID=""
            userName=""
            userSecret=""
            renderChatFeed={(chatAppProps) => <ChatFeed {...chatAppProps} />}    

            />
    );
}

export default App;
```

it shows error while server is running

```
SyntaxError: D:\PROJECTS\APPLICATION\chat_app\src\App.js: Identifier 'ChatFeed' has already been declared. (3:7)

  1 | import { ChatEngine, ChatFeed } from 'react-chat-engine';
  2 |
> 3 | import ChatFeed from './components/chatFeed';
    |        ^
```

Comment: Because you are importing `ChatFeed` is already imported from `react-chat-engine` so try to import like this `import ChatFeed as ChatFeedComponent from './components/chatFeed';` and now use `ChatFeedComponent` as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

The error message says you import ChatFeed twice.

You can fix it remove chatFeed from first line
use this

```
import { ChatEngine} from "react-chat-engine";
import ChatFeed from './components/ChatFeed';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message says it all, you declared `ChatFeed` twice.

You can fix it either by:

1. Renaming your component like `import ChatFeedComponent from './components/chatFeed';`
2. Renaming the named import from `react-chat-engine` like `import { ChatEngine, ChatFeed as ChatFeedComp } from 'react-chat-engine';`

Of course, feel free to use whatever name you like